# Is it possible to create a multi-layer schema in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, schema

For instance so you can specify a department, and then maybe have finer levels of granularity?

```
CREATE SCHEMA hr;
CREATE SCHEMA hr.reportl;
CREATE SCHEMA hr.report2;
```

The last two statements fail.

Comment: No, but you can use roles to further delineate permissions within a schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible.  You can wrap those names in square brackets, but that is not recommended, since it will likely cause a lot of confusion.  For instance:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [hr.report];
```

SELECT statements against objects in the schema would then look like:

```
SELECT * FROM [hr.report].SomeTable;
```